# Spotfire suddenly cant open .accdb

Tags: ms-access, file-type, spotfire

Few days ago I had installed Access Database Engine 32-bit on my 64-bit machine since we are using 32-bit MS software. However this led to some problems and I had to uninstall them again. After this incident Spotfire 7.0.1 refuses to open accdb files. When I go to Add data tables -> File, the file ending *.accdb is simply missing.

I also had a problem with access not finding the correct .dll files. Somebody suggested to manually edit the registry with follow code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00025E01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\5.0\0\win32]
@=hex(2):25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,\
00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,28,00,78,00,38,00,36,00,29,00,\
25,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,53,\
00,68,00,61,00,72,00,65,00,64,00,5c,00,44,00,41,00,4f,00,5c,00,64,00,61,00,\
6f,00,33,00,36,00,30,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{4AC9E1DA-5BAD-4AC7-86E3-24F4CDCECA28}\c.0\0\win32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE14\\ACEDAO.DLL"
```

Maybe I messed up with the file type association?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment so...

Editing the registry should be done with GREAT precaution, and generally speaking, is the last thing you should do. You can really screw a lot of things up doing that. The best thing to do is restore your server from a backup or snapshot if it's in a virtual environment. You should always backup / create restore points or or snapshot (if virtual) your sever before making any big changes.

Judging by your post, your problem is contained to Access. Can you add other types of data files / connections to Spotfire? If so, i'd create a backup immediately while you uninstall / reinstall access, or do what ever else you are going to try.